# Renaming a file with a string from a file of different extension

Tags: java, file, renaming

I need to rename an `.afp` file with name of `.txt` file. I have stumbled across numerous "solutions" while trying to get this thing working and nothing helped.

Let's say I have a txt file in `C:/test/a/Mytes t.txt` and I want to rename `.afp` file which is in `C:/files/b/Testf ile.afp`. This is what I'm trying to do (according to solutions found on this site) and it isn't working. I cut the extension of `.txt` file and get only file name:

```
String fileNameNoExt=fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
//fileName is .txt file name
File file = new File(afpSRC, afpName);
file.renameTo(new File(afpSRC, fileNameNoExt + ".afp"));
```

`afpSRC` contains Path to folder in which `.afp` file is located and `afpName` is the name of the file.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working and `.afp` file name remains the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because `File file = new File(afpSRC, afpName);` doesn't refer a existing file.

I suspect that either `afpSRC` is not the parent path or `afpName` is not the filename. Or both ?

To debug you should check that the file exists first.
If it doesn't exist, throw an exception.
Besides in any way (debug and final code) you should check the returned value by `renameTo()` and handle it consequently.

Here is a sample code :

```
String fileNameNoExt=fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
//fileName is .txt file name
File file = new File(afpSRC, afpName);
if (!file.exists()){
   throw new RuntimeException("file not found = " + file);
}

boolean isRenamed = file.renameTo(new File(afpSRC, fileNameNoExt + ".afp"));
System.out.println("isRenamed = " + isRenamed);
if (!isRenamed){
   // handle the problem
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Java NIO facilities, you will be able to get information through an exception explaining why the rename has failed.

[Files.move(Path from, Path to, CopyOption... options) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)

```
String fileNameNoExt=fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
Path afpPathName = Paths.get(afpSRC, afpName);
Path newPathName = Paths.get(afpSRC, fileNameNoExt + ".afp");
Files.move(afpPathName, newPathName);
```

Comment: Paths.get places a directory separator between each of its arguments.  The third line of code should be `Paths.get(afpSRC, fileNameNoExt + ".afp")` … unless you actually wanted to create a file whose base name is just “.afp”.